# We've played/we've been playing/we played

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

When I want to say that we've been continuously playing Battlefield for the past 2 days, I will use present perfect continuous tense, right?
But what if i want to say that the only game we played in the past 2 days was Battlefield, will I use past simple tense(as it is finished;we are no longer playing battlefield)

> We played battlefield only for the past 2 days

or will I say

> We've played Battlefield only for the past 2 days

(as it connects to present).

I don't really know and would appreciate if someone explained it to me.

Comment: As a Learner: I am not sure how the tense itself would (help to) imply the fact that **only** game you played was **Battlefield**. Also, I think your sentences may mean you hadn't played that game before.

Comment: Where you place *only* matters. What your sentences say is that you never played Battlefield before the last two days; what you probably mean is "We played only Battlefield for the past two days"--that is, you played no other game than Battlefield during that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels somewhat exceptional, as the pluperfect (have played) usually helps ground things firmly in the past. However, in this case the past simple tense is what you are looking for here (though the distinction is subtle). You could realistically use either without any confusion.

More important, as comments have pointed out, is the positioning of the word "only"

1. We only played Battlefield for the past two days
2. We played only Battlefield for the past two days
3. We played Battlefield for only the past two days

Have all got different meanings. In this case you would want to use 2. as "only" will be referring specifically to your choice of game

Answer (score 0):

These are my suggestions. For the past two days we have been playing no other game than Battlefield. The only game we have been playing for the past two days is Battlefield.